# Which is performant multiple request for single doc or single request for 500000 docs (Cloud Firestore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch 50 users from `cloud firestore` and I have two way both works.
But actually I dont know which is performant, as we have a poor internet connection in our country, `if our focus be only fetching not iterating`.

1. The first way (**Single Request**)

   ```
   let tempList = [];
   const matchingUsers = [user1, user2, user3, ..., user50];

   const snap = await db.collection('users').get();

   if (snap.size > 0) {

       sanp.docs.forEach(doc => {

           const data = doc.data();

           matchingUsers.forEach(user => {

               if (data.user === user) {

                   tempList.push(data.user);
               }
           });

       });
   }
   ```
2. The second way (**multiple request**)

   ```
   matchingUsers.forEach(async user => {

       const snap = await db.collection('users').doc(user).get();
       tempList.push(snap.data().user)

   });
   ```

Comment: How many users are there?

Comment: @JonasWilms Thank you, I said I have 500k users in `cloud firestore`, but I want to match `50 local users` with that. Then if the matching was true I retrieve this 50 users data.

Comment: Then I guess iterating 500 000 entries is a lot slower than retrieving 50.

Comment: I tested the Iterating of 500k users is super fast if it is in array, but actually just I dont know, a single fetching time of (`500k users`) and a single fetching performance too.

Comment: Think without Iterating, fetching 500k users in single request is fast or fetching 50 single doc in 50 request ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the first way, you are actually fetching the **entire** users collection and transmit **all the corresponding data** from the backend (Firestore) to your front-end. This is really not efficient, especially if you want to filter 50 users out 500k! Note also that you will pay for 500K reads instead of 50 (see [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)).

So fetching for only the docs you want (i.e. for exactly the 50 users) is the most efficient way. Since the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
const matchingUsers = [user1, user2, user3, ..., user50];
const promises = matchingUsers.map(u => db.collection('users').doc(u).get());

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {

    //results is an array of DocumentSnapshots
    //use any array method, like map or forEach      

    results.map(docSnapshot => {
            console.log(docSnapshot.data());
    });
});
```

As explained in the doc, the advantage of `Promise.all()` is that "it returns a **single Promise** that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled", making it really easy to manage the different asynchronous parallel calls.

Comment: Thank you very much, What about if we filter 50 users out of `50k`

Comment: And could you please let me know, why you have used `map() function`, what do you think if I use `for` instead, if it be faster.

Comment: "What about if we filter 50 users out of 50k" -> this is still not the best solution, especially since you said "we have a poor internet connection in our country". And note that you will pay for 50K reads instead of 50!! If you have only 75 documents in your collection, it may be a viable alternative, but to answer precisely we need to know the size of each doc, your exact internet speed, etc... For knowing which is the faster between `forEach` and `map`, again you should make some measurements. Literature on the net indicates that map is faster, more details through a search on the web.

Comment: Thank you very much and still I dont know, which `promist.all` here will be used as a single request to the server or 50 request.

Comment: `Promise.all` will issue 50 requests in parallel.

Comment: .forEach() does *not* have a return value for each iteration - .map() *does*.  Promise.all() expects an array of promises - so you *must* use .map()